# How to grep in C?

Tags: c, grep, pipe

unsing execlp to grep
what problem this code

```
int main(){
      int fd[2];
      pid_t child_pid;

      pipe(fd);

      if((child_pid = fork())<0){
          perror("fork error");
          exit(0);
      }
      if(child_pid >0){
          close(fd[0]);
          execlp("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-ef", NULL);
      }
      else{
          close(fd[1]);
          execlp("/bin/grep", "/bin/grep", "root", NULL);
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

have problem: /bin/grep: (standard input) : Input/output error

Comment: Is it some homework (to code in C the *equivalent* of `ps -ef | grep telnet`) or are you genuinely seeking in  a C program what processes are using `telnet` ? SO is not a *do-my-homework* service.

Comment: Your question lacks some Linux or POSIX tag.

Comment: SO is not a *fix-my-bug* or *do-my-homework* service.

Comment: No, your problem is a misunderstanding of how Linux processes work (and is not really related to `grep`, `ps`, `telnet`). My answer provided several clues, but I won't do your homework. Spend a few hours reading ALP.

Comment: But you could replace `ps` with `echo `, `grep` with `wc`, and `telnet` with `-l` and your program still remains wrong. So you are not specifically asking about `grep`. ALP has several chapters related to your question, you need to read them.

Answer (score 2):

You might use (on Linux or POSIX) the [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function. Don't forget to `pclose` (not `fclose`) such a stream.

In your particular case of finding a process running `telnet` on Linux,  you don't even need to fork another process for that (and if you wanted to, use [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)). You could directly use `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)). You would for example use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) and related functions to scan `/proc/` to find directories starting with a number (so corresponding to processes). Than for each such directory, e.g. `/proc/1234/` you could read `/proc/1234/cmdline` or [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) its `/proc/1234/exe`. You'll use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to construct strings corresponding to those file paths.

Your program shows some confusion about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). You might want to use [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) and you probably need to call `fork` more than once and use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (freely downloadable) or some other book on Linux programming.

Consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (probably with `-f`) to understand what is going on. Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and to use the `gdb` debugger (with care, it is usable on multi-process programs).

Regarding your new edit ("how to grep in C"), [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and you can use [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) on POSIX to use them in your C code. You don't need to fork a new process.